# Python check matching digit

Tags: python, pattern-matching

I'm trying check whether the short int have digits that contains in long int.  Instead this came out:

```
long int: 198381998
short int: 19
Found a match at   0
Found a match at   1
Found a match at   2
Found a match at   3
Found a match at   4
Found a match at   5
Found a match at   6
Found a match at   7
```

It's suppose to look like this: (Correct one)

```
long int: 198381998
short int: 19
Found a match at   0
Found a match at   5
```

Code:

```
longInt = ( input ("long int: "))
floatLong = float (longInt)
shortInt =  ( input ("short int: "))
floatShort = float (shortInt)

max_digit =  int (math.log10(floatLong)) #Count the no. of long int

i = int(math.log10(floatShort)) # Count the no. shortInt that is being input


for string in range (max_digit):

    if ( shortInt in longInt): # Check whether there is any digit in shortInt 
                               # that contains anything inside longInt
        print ( "Found a match at  ", string)
```

Without using any built-in function of python, no list or string.etc method.

Comment: By the way, why are you manually converting your ints to floats? `math.log10` will do that for you. Also your `max_digit` is off by one: The number of base-`r`-digits of a number `x` is `1 + int(math.log(x, r))`.

Comment: If I didn't manually convert to float, it will give this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in <module>
    max_digit =  int (math.log10(longInt))
TypeError: a float is required
------
because the input is string type

Comment: Ah, that's because the input is a string. You should convert it, but shouldn't it be an int?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your loop for digit positions make "integer slicing" function by using integer `%` (remainder of division aka modulo), `//` (integer division) and `**` (raising to power) operations. Here is the idea:

```
>>> l = 1932319
>>> l // (10**3) % (10**2)
32
```

Then you can compare it to your small integer (using the usual `==`). The rest is your homework, I guess.

NB. The 'in' operation is string operation, so you can't use it.

Comment: Do u mean separating the shorter int to for example 3 and 2 if it is 32? Then compare it? What does raising to power do? Sorry, I'm a beginner in python

Comment: Treat 3 and 2 in the example as a number of zeros to add after 1, because raising 10 to power 3 will give you 1000. Also, 10**2 will give you 100. As for raising to power, take a look at exponentiation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation - it's a math operation, not specific to Python.

Comment: I know that "**" is exponentiation, just didn't think of using that way. 

I try using this:
>>> a = 1932919
>>> a // (10 **4) % (10 **2)
93

So it can be use to check those digit by "shifting" if u corporate them into loop? O.O

Comment: Yes. You can compare your small integer with the "sliced" large int, obtained by the expression.

Comment: I have almost completed it using your method that u have advice on. :) 
May I ask how can I extract the position of the matching digit with long int? Because it is shifting from right to left and not from left to right. I need the position of it starting from the left.

Comment: `for x in range (max_digit):
        y= intLong // (10 ** x) % (10**i)
        if ( y == intShort):
                print ( "Found a match at position ", x)
`

Comment: Yes, something like this. But you may need to adjust i (to be one less) and also printed position (x-i) to match position 0 and 5 in your example.

Answer (score 0):

`shortInt in longInt` yield always True (`'19' in 198381998'` is always `True`).

Use slice:

```
>>> '198381998'[4:6]
'81'
>>> '198381998'[5:7]
'19'
```

---

```
long_int = input("long int: ")
short_int =  input("short int: ")

short_len = len(short_int) # You don't need `math.log10`

for i in range(len(long_int)):
    if long_int[i:i+short_len] == short_int:
        print("Found a match at", i)
```

Comment: I think OP wants to use integer operations rather than strings. Although it's inconsistent with his `if` statement

Comment: @justhalf, I think OP is using Python 3.x. Otherwise, `shortInt in longInt` raises exception.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.x. other than using "in" to compare them what can I use?

Comment: @falsetru It's an excersize in handling integers. Read the smallprint at the end of the question. Your answer is not valid.